# CMake: how to create include path to generated include files

Tags: cmake

I have a project with about 600 directories, containing the source for about a dozen libraries and several dozen programs.  Some of the programs depend upon a C++ header file that is generated from a text file.

How do I cleanly tell CMake how to include that path to the generated header file into the include path for those source files which require it?

Or alternatively, how can I force the generated file to be installed into a known location before CMake attempts to compile those programs?  (This idea is based on the current Makefile system, which generates the header and installs it into the /include directory where all source files can find it.)

Or is there some other alternative?

-- EDIT: added "toy" example --

This example does not work.  I need a way to tell prog1 and prog2 where to find home.h.

My tree:

```
.
|-- prog1/
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|   `-- prog1.cpp
|-- prog2/
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|   `-- prog2.cpp
`-- share/
    `-- dict/
        |-- CMakeLists.txt
        `-- gen.sh*
```

In share/dict:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(dict)

set(SRC foo.c)
set(HEADERS foo.h home.h)

add_custom_target(home
  ALL
  DEPENDS ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/home.h
)

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/home.h
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gen.sh gen.sh
  COMMAND gen.sh ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
)

add_library(dict ${SRC})

install(TARGETS dict DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES ${HEADERS} DESTINATION include)
```

In prog1 (and similarly in prog2):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(prog1)
add_executable(prog1 prog1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(prog1 dict)
install(TARGETS prog1 DESTINATION bin)
```

Comment: Do you know your compiler can be passed arguments to tell it about additional include directories? http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html

Comment: When creating the header, why don't you just change the output path? How do you create it?

Comment: @steveire Yes.  I'm asking how to tell the compiler to look in the out-of-source build directory where the file is generated, for each subdirectory which depends upon it (only some need it).

Comment: @Andreas-Haferburg I think I can do that, but is that proper CMake usage?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After

```
add_library(dict ${SRC})
```

add

```
target_include_directories(dict 
    # The location of the headers before installation 
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include>
    # The location of the headers after installation
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)
```

and read the link I already provided in the comment.

Answer (score 4):

Outputting generated files into out-of-source build directory is an intended way to do it.

Use `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` and `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` as output prefix and as `target_include_directories()` argument.

Comment: Or `set(GENERATED_HEADER_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})` then later `set_target_properties(<target> PROPERTIES INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${GENERATED_HEADER_DIR)`.

Comment: @arrowdodger Either I misunderstand something, or that does not work for `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` as the value is undefined except while Cmake is building in that specific directory.  I've added a hopefully useful example illustration of the situation to the original question.